# “tshark: There are no interfaces on which a capture can be done” in Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, wireshark, tshark

My goal is to capture packets with tshark in Amazon Linux AMI. While typing **tshark** in the command line there's an error:
**"tshark: There are no interfaces on which a capture can be done"**

How to implement the solution from [Wireshark setup Linux for nonroot user](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/7976/wireshark-setup-linux-for-nonroot-user)

```
$ sudo apt-get install wireshark
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common 
$ sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER
$ gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt
```

in Amazon Linux AMI (it's not Ubuntu)?

Comment: Well, first question—does it work as a privileged (root) user?

Comment: it does work. i want to configure it without having to sudo tshark

Answer (score 4):

#### Using sudo

I think you need to find out what interface is being used for your network and then just tell `tshark` about it.

#### Example

Network devices present on my box.

```
$ ip addr|grep '^[0-9]'|awk '{print $2}'
lo:
eth0:
wlan0:
```

Run `tshark`:

```
$ sudo tshark -i wlan0 | head -5
..start seeing output from tshark...
```

#### Using capabilities

The Amazon AMI instances are based on CentOS so you may be able to use the following steps to accomplish what you're after.

```
$ sudo groupadd wireshark
$ sudo usermod -a -G wireshark saml
$ setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/sbin/dumpcap
```

The above creates the Unix group `wireshark`, adds the user `saml` to it, and then adds the capabilities using the tool `setcap` to allow others access to the `dumpcap` file.

#### Example

```
$ tshark -i wlan0
Capturing on wlan0
  0.000000 108.160.163.38 -> 192.168.1.20 HTTP HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/plain)
  0.087199 108.160.163.38 -> 192.168.1.20 TCP http > 38987 [ACK] Seq=180 Ack=352 Win=83 Len=0 TSV=144745749 TSER=195830096
  0.253077 192.168.1.20 -> 255.255.255.255 DB-LSP-DISC Dropbox LAN sync Discovery Protocol
  0.253360 192.168.1.20 -> 192.168.1.255 DB-LSP-DISC Dropbox LAN sync Discovery Protocol
  0.779785 192.168.1.20 -> 74.125.225.115 HTTP HEAD / HTTP/1.1 
...
```

You can read more about Linux' `capabilities` facility via the man pages, `man capabilities`.

#### References

- [Running Wireshark as You](https://blog.wireshark.org/2010/02/running-wireshark-as-you/)
- [Linux Capabilities - Making them work](http://ols.fedoraproject.org/OLS/Reprints-2008/hallyn-reprint.pdf)
- [Introduction to Linux Capabilities and ACL's](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/introduction-linux-capabilities-and-acls)
- [This is the Linux kernel capabilities FAQ](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/linux-privs/kernel-2.2/capfaq-0.2.txt)
- [Using Capabilities](http://www.lst.de/~okir/blackhats/node125.html)

Comment: Thank you. But my goal is to allow using tshark without sudo.

Comment: @user1264304 thats what the 'capabilities' bit was all about.

Comment: @user1264304 - see updates.

Comment: See also: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges